# Clojure + Clojurescript: Macro to read code of current file

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

## What I've Already Tried

```
(defmacro magic []
  (slurp *file*))
```

This works fine in clojure, but not in clojurescript (atleast not with lein figwheel).

## Original Question

I need the following to work in both Clojure and Clojurescript. I think a macro is the right solution, but I'm open to other techniques.

I want a way to read the *current* file as a string. For example,

```
(ns my-test
  (:require blah))

(def foo 20)

(println (blah/magic))
```

this should then result in (being printed out)

```
(ns my-test
  (:require blah))

(def foo 20)

(println (blah/magic))
```

If I only needed this to work in Clojure, I could do funny things with the current file and reading it at run time. However, I need this also to work in Clojurescript (and I don't want to setup some REST API to serve *.cljs files) -- thus, is there some way to do this at compile time via some macro?

### Clarification

Suppose you wanted to write a "cheating quine" -- how would you do it? Probably something like `(println (slurp *file*))`. Now, what's the problem? This doesn't work in clojurescript when running under lein figwheel.

Comment: What do you need to do that slurp and spit won't do for you?

Comment: @jmargolisvt: name of the current file. In clojure, I can get name of current file via *file* -- in cljs, there appears to be funky things going on.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @AlanThompson: my example above is poorly written. The above should be a cheating "quine" -- a program that prints itself.

Comment: @AlanThompson: does the above clarification make sense? (Sorry for the confusing question).

Comment: As you note in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230525/writing-a-cheating-quine-in-clojurescript, figwheel adds some bootstrap code to the temporary file.  Is that the only problem?  What happens if you don't use figwheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Reader Conditionals like this:

```
(defn build-list []
  (list #?@(:clj  [5 6 7 8]
            :cljs [1 2 3 4])))
```

Please see the docs here:

http://clojure.org/guides/reader_conditionals

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Using-cljc

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to modify the currently executing source code, you can always construct a string and use `eval`:

```
(eval (read-string "(defn darth [] (println \"I have the ultimate power now...\" ))" ))

(darth)
;=> I have the ultimate power now...
```

However, since ClojureScript is compiled, I don't think there is any simple way of finding the source original source code, if that's what you're after.

**UPDATE 2**

It's an interesting problem.  The closest I've come so are is something like this:

```
(ns clj.core)

(defmacro fred [& forms]
  (doseq [f forms]
    (println `~f)))

(fred 
  (+ 1 2)
  (* 2 3)
)

(defn -main [& args])
```

with results:

```
> lein run    
(+ 1 2)
(* 2 3)
```

Comment: I've used reader conditionals before, they're the clojure equiv of C's #ifdefs -- however, it's not clear to me how they're relevant in this question.

Comment: 1) thanks for your patience 2) I still don't think I have properly explained the question. Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230525/writing-a-cheating-quine-in-clojurescript make sense?

Comment: You can't really do the `slurp`, since CLJS is compiled (into javascript). So, when it runs, only the compiled code JS code is available, not the CLJS source code.

Comment: I agree that at *runtime*, this is not possible. Thus, I was hoping to play with some macro magic and do it at *compile* time. :-)

Comment: Update 2 is nice but does not preserve "formatting (i.e. line/column)" -- now, with meta data, one we get the column/line of (), [], {} ... but not complicated expressions, like (+\n x\n y\n 2) -- one only gets the column/line number of the (, not the +, x, or y. [I'm trying to display CLJS snippet output + actual CLJS code, thus I'd prefer to get the actual CLJS code, as it's formatted].

Comment: Yes, formatting will be a problem since macro output is only intended for the compiler -> whitespace doesn't matter.  Looks like a challenge! You could always copy the Java example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Comment: Quine isn't the end goal though. (It was mentioned only to explain the problem). I'm using figwheel + devcards -- and I want a side by side "here is your code, here is the devcard output". Oh well, I'm now pretty convinced this is not do-able. Thanks for all your patience + help though. :-)

Comment: Perhaps you should send and email to the author, he may have some good ideas for enhancements. An email to the Clojure Google groups mailing list would also be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Very late to the party here but I had a similar problem and after a day of searching I found the ClojureScript counterpart to `*file*` to be `cljs.analyzer/*cljs-file*`.

You also need to be careful to create a macro-only namespace (with nothing but `defmacro`s) for your macro and make that a .clj file. Furthermore, in my experience, that namespace had to be required with the `(:require-macros [your-macro-ns])` rather than the normal `(:require ...)`.

So the answer to your question would be

#### my_macro.clj

```
(ns my-macro)

(defmacro compile-time-slurp-self []
  (slurp cljs.analyzer/*cljs-file*))
```

#### main.cljs

```
(ns main
  (:require-macros [my-macro]))

(def foo 420)

(println (my-macro/compile-time-slurp-self))
```

It should be noted that, since slurp needs Clojure, this only works with the Clojure-based ClojureScript compiler, not the new bootstrapped compiler that, itself, runs on ClojureScript. From what I understand the latter is mostly used for browser-based REPLs and dev environments where Java is not available so as long as you're not building your code in the browser you should be fine.

Comment: What would be the command to compile this? I got the error `clj -m cljs.main --optimizations advanced -c hello_world.core
Unexpected error (FileNotFoundException) compiling at (REPL:1).
Could not locate my_macro__init.class, my_macro.clj or my_macro.cljc on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.'

Comment: Might just be that my-macro.clj needs to be named my_macro.