# Writing a "cheating" Quine in Clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Suppose we wanted to write a cheating quine in clojure, we could do:

```
(ns cheating-quine)
... stuff here doesn't really matter ...
(println (slurp *file*))
```

Now, this does not work in Lein Figwheel because the value of *file* ends up being something like /tmp/form-init########.clj, and contains bootstrapping code of some sort.

Question: how can we get this "cheating" quine to work in clojurescript?

Note: the goal is NOT to write a quine. The goal is to write a cljs program which *has access to the file it's defined in*. This whole "cheating quine" thing is trying to explain the problem better then my previous failed attempt of

[Clojure + Clojurescript: Macro to read code of current file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229721/clojure-clojurescript-macro-to-read-code-of-current-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheating solution is to distribute the source code (e.g. put it in resources and serve it as a file) and compile a bootstrap to load and execute code, and get it to pull down your file, and in the file load the same file... that way it can do a HTTP request for the code that is currently running, and execute it. This is essentially how ClojureScript browser REPLs such as http://clojurescript.io/ work... They compile and execute incoming code on the fly. clojuresript.io is a good working example of ClojureScript bootstrapping if you are interested in it, but a word of caution, there is quite a lot going on so expect to invest quite some time :)

Comment: clojurescript.io is awesome! thanks for sharing! it looks like a futuristic UI